# Set password on iPhone 13?

Tags: password, iphone

I was recently considering buying an **Apple iPhone 13 Pro**.

I like to ensure all of my devices are protected with passwords, having had a prior negative experience with a rogue organisation which could effortlessly crack my phone's PIN code. This is not to forget that an adversary can also force one into using biometrics. I have also read that iPhones made since 2017 are no longer supported by Cellebrite cellular cracking and forensics suite, but I like to be cautious.

Could someone please confirm if it is possible to use a pass**word** instead of a pass**code** for an Apple iPhone 13? Through my numerous searches it appears that Apple only supports PIN and biometrics.

Comment: Through my numerous searches it appears that Apple only supports PIN and biometrics.  ...... That is all that is supported natively.  I do not think you can effortlessly crack the PIN.  The FBI needs Apple's help not always granted.

Comment: @John You are correct, Apple uses a special technique so PINs cannot be bruteforced easily, it is Android phones that are susceptible to bruteforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, alphanumeric codes have been introduced with iOS 9 in 2015

The "Passcode" options for iOS 15 are:

- 4-Digit Numeric Code
- 6-Digit Numeric Code
- Custom Numeric Code
- Custom Alphanumeric Code (i.e. Password)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an alphanumeric code (I.e. a password) to unlock your iPhone. I do not know if it is natively visible, but even if it isn’t, you can make it visible using an iOS configuration profile.

Comment: What is an iOS configuration profile?

Comment: Using configuration profiles, enterprises can enforce e. g. security guidelines like password requirements or VPN connections. Just do a little googling, with profiles you can do incredibly useful things to customize your phone a little more. And you can force even more privacy by disabling Siri logging or other tracking.

Comment: This can be done with an ordinary iPhone, without having to jailbreak it? 0_0

Comment: Yes, it can. As a company you cannot use jailbroken phones…